# Props de componente vacíos mediante Redux

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, redux, axios

Tengo una aplicación en React y Redux que trae contenido de un JSON local mediante `axios`. Eso lo almaceno en el state mediante una action y un reducer.
Todo parece funcionar bien, hasta que intento mapear el array que viene en el JSON, para iterarlo, y noto que las props están vacías.
Hice un `console.log` del `state` dentro de `mapStateToProps`, dentro del componente, y me devuelve dos logs: uno con el array vacío, y luego otro con los datos correspondientes.
¿Qué estoy haciendo mal que no puedo pasar el state como props a ese componente?

**JSON**

```
{
     "items": 
            ["item1", "item2", "item3", "item4"],
     "itemDescriptions": [
            {
                "title": "Here the title",
            }
      ]
}
```

**Component.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { fetchData } from './../actions';

class Content extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.fetchData();
    }

    renderData = () => {
        if(docs) {
            return this.docs.map(doc => {
              return <h1>{doc}</h1>
            });
        }
        return <h1>Empty</h1>
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>{this.renderData()}</div>
        );
    }
}

const mapsStateToProps = (state) => {
    console.log(state)
    return {
        data: state.data
    }
}

export default connect(mapsStateToProps, {
    fetchData: fetchData
})(Content);
```

**actions/index.js**

```
import axios from 'axios';

export const fetchData = () => async (dispatch) => {
    const localData = axios.create({
        baseURL: 'http://localhost:3000/data'
    })

    const response = await localData.get('/data.json')

    dispatch({
        type: 'FETCH_DATA',
        payload: response.data
    });
}
```

**reducers/index.js**

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';

const dataReducer = (state = [], action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'FETCH_DATA':
            return [...state, action.payload];
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

export default combineReducers({
    data: dataReducer
});
```

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import reducers from './reducers';

import './index.css';
import App from './components/App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

const composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;
const store = createStore(reducers, /* preloadedState, */ composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(thunk)));

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <App /> 
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: ¿Podrías poner el código en JsFiddle o algún sitio similar? Sería de gran ayuda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema era que se estaba generando un array nuevo dentro de otro porque en el reducer escribí `return [...state, action.payload`, cuando en realidad, para agregar al array existente debe escribirse `return [...state, ...action.payload]`.
No había nada en mis props más que un array anidado dentro de otro, por eso no podía mapearlo.

Answer (score 0):

En `mapsStateToProps` estás asignando lo retornado al prop `data`

```
const mapsStateToProps = (state) => {
    console.log(state)
    return {
        data: state.data
    }
}
```

sin embargo, al renderear la información, estás accediendo a `this.docs`

```
renderData = () => {
    if(docs) {
        return this.docs.map(doc => {
          return <h1>{doc}</h1>
        });
    }
    return <h1>Empty</h1>
}
```

basado en el json que muestras, deberías acceder a `this.props.data.items` al momento de iterar.

Comment: ¡Gracias! Eso solamente fue un typo cuando generé el post aquí.